# check if more than 1 value in an array in angular6

Tags: angular6

I need to check if there is more than one specified value exist in an array.

This is my code I am having. Here 'animal_list' is an array which has more than 2 values. This code will return if the array has the value 'cow'.

```
animal_list.includes('cow')
```

Now I need to check if the array has 2 values 'cow' and 'cat'.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try (animal_list.includes('cow') && animal_list.includes('cat'))